# Converting to base $-2$

Tags: computer-science, number-systems

How to convert a number given in Decimal to negative base.?

For eg I want to convert $67$ given in  decimal base to base $-2$.?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_base Also: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=convert+67+to+base+-2

Comment: You might enjoy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quater-imaginary_base, which discusses an imaginary base system.

Comment: I've removed [tag:algebra] tag, since we don't use algebra tag anymore, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/473/the-use-of-the-algebra-tag/3081#3081) for details

Answer (score 6):

$67 = \color{red}1 \cdot (-2)^6 + \color{red}0 \cdot (-2)^5 + \color{red}0 \cdot (-2)^4 + \color{red}0 \cdot (-2)^3 + \color{red}1 \cdot (-2)^2 + \color{red}1 \cdot (-2)^1 + \color{red}1 \cdot (-2)^0$, so $67_{10} = 1000111_{-2}$.

An interesting feature of this base system is that you can represent negative numbers without a minus sign. For example, $-67_{10} = 11001101_{-2}$.